# how to check if another application is changing/rewriting memory

Tags: c#, memory, process

I've been trying to figure out how to do this. For example, I'm creating a client-side application for a game GTA San Andreas multiplayer (samp) and for that game there are hacks for example aimbot. Now what that aimbot does is I guess it rewrites the memory for gta_sa.exe so it aims at players, it changes these addresses

[link to the page](https://www.gtamodding.com/wiki/Memory_Addresses_(SA))

Now, what would be the best way to check when memory is changed for example 0xB7CD98?

I've been trying to find a proper logic for this but I can't seem to do so.

```
/*
    SA:MP Aimbot
    Hold down fire & aim key
*/
if (cAimbot)
{
    ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)0xB6F5F0,  &gpoint, 4, 0);

    if ((gpoint > 0) && (t == 0))
    {
        t = 1;
    }
    if (gpoint > 0)
    {
        pmtrx1 = gpoint + 0x14;
        ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)pmtrx1, &pmtrx1, 4, 0);
        xpos1 = pmtrx1 + 0x30;
        ypos1 = pmtrx1 + 0x34; 
        ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)xpos1, &fxpos1, 4, 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)ypos1, &fypos1, 4, 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)0xB6F9CC, &fcxpos, 4, 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)0xB6F9D0, &fcypos, 4, 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)0xB6F3B8,  &ptarget, 4, 0);
        pped = ptarget + 0x79C;
        ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)pped,  &pped, 4, 0);

        if (pped > 0)
        {
            pvectorx = pped + 0x44;
            pvectory = pped + 0x48;
            ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)pvectorx, &fpvectorx, 4, 0);
            ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)pvectory, &fpvectory, 4, 0);
            pmtrx2 = pped + 0x14;
            ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)pmtrx2, &pmtrx2, 4, 0);
            xpos2 = pmtrx2 + 0x30;
            ypos2 = pmtrx2 + 0x34;
            ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)xpos2, &fxpos2, 4, 0);
            ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)ypos2, &fypos2, 4, 0);
            php = pped + 0x540;
            ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)php, &fphp, 4, 0);
            if (fphp > 0)
            { 
                fxpos2a = fxpos2;
                fypos2a = fypos2;
                aa = fabs(fcxpos-fxpos2);
                ab = fabs(fcypos-fypos2); 
                ac = sqrt(aa*aa+ab*ab);
                alpha = asin(aa/ac);
                beta = acos(aa/ac);
                if ((fxpos1 > fxpos2)&&(fypos1 < fypos2))
                {
                    beta = -beta;
                }
                if ((fxpos1 > fxpos2)&&(fypos1 > fypos2))
                {
                    beta = beta;
                }
                if ((fxpos1 < fxpos2)&&(fypos1 > fypos2))
                {
                    beta = (alpha + (3.14/2));
                }
                if ((fxpos1 < fxpos2)&&(fypos1 < fypos2))
                {
                    beta = (-alpha - (3.14/2));
                }
                camxpos = beta+0.0389;
                // Rotate camera
                WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)0xB6F258, (LPVOID)&camxpos, 4, NULL);                             
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to distinguish a memory write made by your own application from the aimbot. For every check you make, the hack can simply do the exact same thing your code does. In fact, it's not that much harder to make the aimbot code run in your process in the first place.

But even if you could, the hack would just move to a different level. Instead of writing things "to memory", you'd change the way the mouse reports its movements. Say, using a DirectX hook, or having a custom mouse driver, or even having a device that pretends to be a mouse, but isn't. Don't forget that you're already assuming the client is sabotaged *on purpose* - the only things that are reliable in any way are things that the server can verify with enough accuracy. With aimbots, I'm afraid whatever you do will introduce tons of false positives without really catching the aimbots - as soon as you introduce a check, the aimbot will simply change its behaviour to pass the check, just like with the direct memory manipulation. And at the same time, pretty much each of these checks is going to exclude some honest players (when I was still playing FPS games a lot, my aiming looked a bit like the aimbots of the time - I kept looking all around me all the time and very quickly and precisely aiming straight for the head; add just a tiny bit of slowdown to your aimbot, and you can't distinguish it from a skilled player).

Comment: Hmm, I suppose there should be another way. I edited my post with an aimbot source code can you please take a look and see is this detectable ?

Comment: @Nathaniel It is *detectable* - that's not the problem. The problem is that it isn't *distinguishable* from normal operation. For example, you can set a hardware breakpoint on a memory write to that location. But what do you do when the write happens? A write from your own process looks the same. If you rely on any particular ordering of reads and writes for example, the aimbot will just do the same ordering. And don't forget those writes are quite frequent - your trap code can't do anything complicated.

Comment: Understandable. So basically there is not that much that I can do. But the thing that bothers me is that I have an application made by another developer which does the similar thing. Basically when an aimbot application is opened it automatically closes it and I supposed that was because of memory reading.

Comment: @Nathaniel Well, you can always look how they do it (provided the license allows this, of course). It may be that they make protection against a certain particular aimbot and the aimbot author didn't bother to overcome that. It may even be as simple as looking for a known process name and killing it immediately - and while overcoming that kind of defence is very easy (say, rename the executable), someone still needs to do it. If the hackers don't care enough to bother, the defence can work. Check if it kills my tool - https://github.com/Luaancz/AutoPoke

Comment: Well checking for process name is not doing that much, simple rename and you can use the hack again. I will check your tool when I get home I'm at work on mac and application is only for windows.

Comment: And can you please check this out https://github.com/Whitetigerswt/SAMP_AC_Extension/blob/master/SAMP_AC_Extension/Memory.cs

Comment: @Nathaniel Actually, that only seems to be checking that the models/textures weren't modified (in a certain simple way). It's probably looking for client modifications designed to make things easier to see (and hear) - an example of this in Counter-Strike is here https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/4a/9d/42/4a9d4274f91528c9097698b1203e05c7.jpg If that's part of the aimbot (as in the case I posted), it will detect the modifications and terminate. But it cannot detect the aiming itself - it just seems that this particular aimbot either relies on this, or provides it as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really big question...

In general every process in OS Windows have own virtual memory address space - so memory address 0xB7CD98 in process game is not the same in  for example aim bot ( and you even not sure this address on this time on RAM or on disk cashe). Where store and how - this is work Memory Manager - this is part of OS kernel.

I suggest you ["Windows Internals Book"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - there you can find right answers...

Answer (score 0):

You may look cheat engine

Cheat engine allows you to check who reaches that memory [sample picture from UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKs85.png)

This program is all about modifing other programs(games mostly) RAM value.

Their forum might be more helpful than SO.

Cheat engine [tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKs85.png)